# Reactive Input Impedance for Current Noise

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

I am reading about op amp noise in the app note [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-047.pdf). Page 3 mentions:

"Current noise is only important when it flows in an impedance, and thus generates a noise voltage. Maintaining relatively low impedances at the input of an op amp circuit contributes markedly to minimizing the effects of current noise."

For the source impedance does this take into account only real R or complex impedance Z? If my source is 1 MegOhm in parallel with 1 pF capacitor do I take the equivalent impedance of both to calculate current noise?

Answer (score 1):

> If my source is 1 MegOhm in parallel with 1 pF capacitor do I take
>   the equivalent impedance of both to calculate current noise?

Yes you do; it's the voltage that develops across the **impedance** due to the current noise flowing that is the important thing to consider and this usually means R || C.